# Why is my DatePeriod object empty?

Tags: php, datetime

Why is my DatePeriod object empty? Times and Interval are valid. What am I missing?

```
$datestart    = new DateTime('2015-01-01 00:00:00');
$dateinterval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$dateend      = new DateTime('2015-03-31 23:59:59');
$dateend      = $dateend->modify( '+1 day' ); 
var_dump($datestart);
var_dump($dateinterval);
var_dump($dateend);

$period = new DatePeriod(
    $datestart,
    $dateinterval,
    $dateend
);

var_dump($period);
```

My result:

```
class DateTime#1 (3) {
  public $date =>
  string(19) "2015-01-01 00:00:00"
  public $timezone_type =>
  int(3)
  public $timezone =>
  string(16) "America/New_York"
}
class DateInterval#2 (8) {
  public $y =>
  int(0)
  public $m =>
  int(0)
  public $d =>
  int(1)
  public $h =>
  int(0)
  public $i =>
  int(0)
  public $s =>
  int(0)
  public $invert =>
  int(0)
  public $days =>
  bool(false)
}
class DateTime#3 (3) {
  public $date =>
  string(19) "2015-04-01 23:59:59"
  public $timezone_type =>
  int(3)
  public $timezone =>
  string(16) "America/New_York"
}
class DatePeriod#4 (0) {
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to see?

Comment: My object isn't empty, is this your full code?

Comment: Mine vardumps an empty object. Even weirder.

Comment: seems to be related to the version - see: http://3v4l.org/XZqkY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over your $period displaying the dates:

```
foreach($period as $date) {
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d'), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Your dateperiod isn't like a pre-populated array, it generates the relevant data each iteration

Comment: So why did the other people's work, and mine didn't, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: That I don't know: you hadn't edited your output result into the question when I posted.... I'd just guessed that you were expecting to see a list of results that would be returned as you iterated; but I'd tested mine in 3val.org so knew that iterating generated the correct result in all appropriate versions